# Autohotkey - need to reload

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

i am using autohotkey with great pleasure, but for some reason i need to reload the scripts / replace the instance every ~60 minutes. they are still active in my taskbar, but the shortcuts are no longer active. Does anyone have an idea what causes this / what suppresses the autohotkey (Windows? Virus Scanner)? I am using  Dell Latitude running 64bit Windows 7 with AVG virus scanner. Many thanks in advance, W

Comment: Not a direct answer: Perhaps the script is "stuck" waiting for something specific to happen, if it happens again try double clicking the AHK icon in the tray icon to see the lines most recently executed. You could also add  a settimer command which automatically reloads your script every 30 minutes, a kludge but might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Lintalist suggested, I'd also make sure you're on the latest version of AHK, as downloaded/maintained at ahkscript.org

I'm running with a rather large startup script on 64 bit win7 and used to see what you describe all the time before I knew about the split in the AHK community.  I was still using www.autohotkey.com, not realizing the rift that was present in the community there and that actual development had moved on to ahkscript.org

HTH,
HAND

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Autohotkey with great pleasure.
I have also faced the same problem in the past, but I have solved it now like that, not a proper way but OK, it's working.
Let's assume your Reloaded File name is MainScript.AHK
You need to create another file like RestartScript.AHK

In the MainScript.AHK file, add a timer of 59 min and 55 seconds, and at the end of MainScript.AHK you need to add this script:

```
run, C:\add your path here\RestartScript.ahk

ExitApp
```

This code will start the RestartScript file and exit MainScript.AHK.

and in RestartScript.AHK you need to add this script:

```
sleep, 3000   ;  3 Seconds time

run, C:\add your path here\MainScript.ahk

ExitApp
```

This will restart your MainScript after 3 seconds. You can reduce the time according to your wish.

It is not a professional way to get it but it will solve your problem at the moment.

I am also giving you a Good Timer you can edit and use according to your requirements, it is set on 5 Seconds you can change as you desire... in Your Case You need to change 5 to 3600 (Means One Hour Time) Enjoy Now.

```
^+T::

Settimer, Counter, 1000
Var := 5


Counter: 

{
    Var--
    Tooltip, %Var%`n, 
}

if var = 0
{
        settimer, counter, off
        tooltip
    SoundBeep
}

Return
```

Answer (score -2):

I've found a better approach. Simply add this in the script before the hotkey:

```
sleep 3600000
Reload,
Alt:: ; your hotkey
SEND, FIN MY SOLUTION   ;your functions
```

Remember that the autohotkey script does not need any keys to be activated, therefore "Reload" will be activated, even if it does not have a key that activates it after 3600 seconds.

Also you can use this:

```
SetTimer,
CheckTime, 3600000
Return
CheckTime:
Reload
Return ; add all this before your script
Alt::  ; YOUR HOTKEY
Msgbox FIND THE SOLUTION!  ; your functions
```

if this does not work you should add this to the beginning:

```
#Persistent
```

(https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Persistent.htm)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your answer includes code. Please [edit] and use the help in the sidebar to format your answer for readability. Thanks for contributing.

Comment: if you do sleep on first line, i don't think that hotkey will actually work...